# Style not working on GridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I I want to enable editing by a single click in a telerik RadGridView with multiple CheckBox columns defines as follows:

```
        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding someSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding someBinding}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding someBinding1}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding someBinding2}"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

I defined the following style but it doesn't work

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn}">
            <Setter Property="AutoSelectOnEdit" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="EditTriggers" Value="CellClick"/>
            <Setter Property="IsThreeState" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
```

This does not work. However, if I set those properties to each column individually it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a problem with the way you defined your style so it must be the initial section.

I think `ItemsSource="{Binding someSource}"` should be like this `ItemsSource="{Binding Path= someSource}"`

Not too sure as I haven't tried but hope this works.

Comment: tried it, same results .... I don't know why but no style seems to apply to the RadGridView ... I also tried setting a style to cells like this
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadGridViewCell"> 
     <EventSetter Event="MouseUp" Handler="Cell_MouseUp" /> 
</Style> 
but no results ....